# What am I not understanding about hosting a Java web app?

Tags: java, node.js, web-applications, firebase, web-hosting

I am new to Java and I am trying to [host a Java web app using Firebase](https://www.firebase.com).

### Problem

My problem appears to be that my `index.html` file does not exist in my Java file structure. Therefore, I can not "point to it" in my `firebase.json` file.

### Question

1. What am I not understanding about how to host a Java web app?
2. Do java web apps have an `index.html` file when they are deployed (which, apparently, Firebase requires)?
3. What can I do to successfully host my Java web app?

---

#### Firebase hosting setup instructions:

> SETUP & INSTALLATION
>
> **First Time Installation**
>
> You should have Node.js installed (you do not need to run Node, just have it installed)
>
> `$npm install -g firebase-tools` or `$sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`
>
> **Updating Previously Installed Firebase Tools**
>
> `$npm update -g firebase-tools` or `$sudo npm update -g firebase-tools`
>
> DEPLOY YOUR WEBSITE
>
> 1. `$cd` into your website directory and run `$firebase init`
> 2. Then deploy your website with `$firebase deploy`

---

#### My error message:

When I follow the hosting instructions and browse to `https://my-example-firebase.firebaseio.com/` I get the following error message.

> **Page Not Found**
>
> This file does not exist and there was no `index.html` found in the current directory or `404.html` in the root directory.
>
> **Why am I seeing this?**
>
> You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your `firebase.json` and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an `index.html` file.

---

#### My firebase.json

```
{
  "firebase": "my-example-firebase",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my `firebase.json` file assumes my `root` directory is my `public` directory. However, that does not contain an `index.html` file. Therefore, this is what I think I am missing about the structure of a Java web app and file structure. There IS NO `index.html` file.

---

#### My file structure

(as scaffolded by Eclipse) (partially) looks like the following.

```
root
  Deployment descriptor: myproject
  JAX-WS Web Services
  Java Resources
  Javascript Resources
  build
    src
      com.example.myproject
        MyprojectUI.java
          MyprojectUI
    test
    libraries
  WebContent
  ivy.xml
  ivysettings.xml
```

I looked all through it and there is no `index.html` file. I'm wondering if I need to maybe compile something into HTML and Javascript? Then serve that file? I'm lost and confused. Please somebody help.

Comment: What is the content of your firebase.json? That would be a place for us to start. I suppose we must assume that you did everything in the instructions? What is in the root directory?

Comment: @ShawnMehan: Please see my edits under **My firebase.json** and **My file structure**. Yes, I did everything in the instructions. The root directory contents (first level) are contained in the edits to **My file structure**. All help is welcome at this point. And greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is for hosting static assets only, so HTML, JavaScript, CSS, images, etc.

Firebase Hosting cannot be used to run your Java web application.