# Full stack website with firebase hosting, Marionette, RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, marionette, firebase-hosting

I've been using a lot of firebase lately and I'm looking into building a web app and hosting it on firebase as well. I know Firebase hosting lets you deploy html/css/javascript files, but is there any way to customize the server code to handle certain jobs on the server side? For example I'm concerned about putting my API keys (including firebase) on the client side since anyone can really see them. And I'm not too sure about encrypting things on the client side.

If this is not a feature currently, I hope Firebase introduces it soon! Maybe an option run Node/Express for their hosting. :)

Comment: This would seem like a question to ask their support team, not a website about asking and answering programming questions.

Comment: Well i was interested in seeing if anyone has a workaround that I'm not aware of.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217764/what-am-i-not-understanding-about-hosting-a-java-web-app. Depending on the API keys you're talking about, there may be no reason for concern. Seehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678876/how-does-firebase-prevent-attackers-from-accessing-a-firebase-database-when-app#comment62840183_37678876

Comment: Ah okay I see. Firebase database rules seem like they'll do the job for me. Thank you!